# How to Compare lists of values (Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, string-comparison

I am looking to compare cells containing a list of comma separated strings to a column containing solutions made up of comma-separated lists.

[My test data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQRgU.png)

Each cell in the "Test lists" column will need to be checked against every one of the cells in the "Possible Solutions" column. If any exist that contain all of the values of the list we are currently testing, it should return TRUE. Otherwise, FALSE. It is OK if the possible solution contains MORE values, just not less.

The image above contains the best solution to this I have managed to work out so far ... the "Should be" column shows the answer I am expecting.

Any suggestions on other things I might try?

Comment: I suggest you share a link to a spreadsheet containing *realistic* data and expected returns, so that the volunteer contributors have an immediate space and data for building and testing formula approaches. By *realistic*, I mean that you should consider all facets of the data. For instance, will all comma-separated entries in all areas really only consist of *one word* (e.g., apples, peaches) and never multiple words (e.g., red grapes, green grapes, pink grapefruit)? Will both "grape" and "grapefruit" (substrings) ever exits? Will there really be commas at the end of lists as shown? Etc...

Comment: This is a realistic case - the data has been simplified, but it represents actual use. It is a very small part of a larger problem, and I already have all of the other parts of the solution completed. Looking for a direction, not a solution.

Comment: To clarify what you are saying (for other volunteers here who may yet choose to engage): 1.) All listed entries will always be one word; 2.) commas may or may not appear at the ends of lists with nothing after them; 3.) all entries will always appear in lists in alphabetical order; 4) no substrings will every exist anywhere between any list (e.g., "grape" and "grapfruit," "orange" and "oranges," etc.). As you've noted that this formula step is "a very small part of a larger problem," understand that should any of those conditions later be broken, a provided solution, if any, may not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. Paste in cell D2 and drag!

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(N(ARRAYFORMULA( 
    LEN(FILTER($A$2:$A, $A$2:$A<>"")) 
  - LEN(REGEXREPLACE(FILTER($A$2:$A, $A$2:$A<>""), SUBSTITUTE($B2, ", ", "|"), ""))
  = LEN(SUBSTITUTE($B2, ", ", "")) 
)))) > 0
```

The general idea here is to extract all test list elements from a given possible solution list, and then check whether the number of characters removed equals the length of the test list. If that's true, then the test list is contained within the solution list.

The inner `ARRAYFORMULA()` extends that search scheme to every possible solution list (i.e. to all of column A); the outer `ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(N(...))) > 0` returns `TRUE` if any of the possible solutions pass the test.

Comment: Thanks John K.! That solution fit the bill perfectly. Was able to adapt it and fold it into my working solution seamlessly. I don't have much experience using ARRAYFORMULA in this manner, so I thank you for the tip. Much appreciated!

Comment: Glad it worked out—you’re welcome!